# Moving the camera in the direction it is facing

Tags: c#, xna, camera, rotation, frame-rate

I've followed a tutorial on how to make a first person camera rotate and move in a 3D world in XNA on the Microsoft website. But when I rotate the camera along it's Y axis, it doesn't move the direction it is rotated/facing, instead it moves as if it was facing the direction it was originally faced.

**Here's my code:**

```
static Vector3 avatarPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
static Vector3 cameraPosition = avatarPosition;
Vector3 cameraReference = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
// Create a vector pointing the direction the camera is facing.
Matrix world = Matrix.CreateWorld(new Vector3(0, -1, 0), Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up);
Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(0));
int Rot = 0;
Vector3 worldVector = new Vector3(5,-2, 0);
Matrix view, proj;
Vector3 cameraLookat;
Update()
{
    world = Matrix.CreateWorld(worldVector, Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up);
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        avatarPosition += new Vector3(0.2f, 0f, 0);
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        avatarPosition += new Vector3(-0.2f, 0f, 0);
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        avatarPosition += new Vector3(0f, 0f, -0.2f);
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        avatarPosition += new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.2f);

    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        Rot += 1;
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        Rot += -1;

    rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(Rot));
    // Create a vector pointing the direction the camera is facing.
    Vector3 transformedReference = Vector3.Transform(cameraReference, rotationMatrix);
    // Calculate the position the camera is looking at.
    cameraLookat = transformedReference + cameraPosition;
    // Set up the view matrix and projection matrix.
    view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraLookat, new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    proj = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio,
                                          0.1f, 1000);
    cameraPosition = avatarPosition;
 }
```

Can someone please tell me why the camera does not travel the way it is rotated? Or can someone please just give me the damn code to make one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appears the problem you are experiencing is coming from this area of the code:

```
if (IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    avatarPosition += new Vector3(0.2f, 0f, 0);
if (IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
    avatarPosition += new Vector3(-0.2f, 0f, 0);
if (IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
    avatarPosition += new Vector3(0f, 0f, -0.2f);
if (IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
    avatarPosition += new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.2f);
```

Instead of translating the avatarPosition directly along the x or z axis, it should be using the direction you're pointing which appears to be your transformedReference variable.

For instance, to move forward the way the camera is facing:

```
if (IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    avatarPosition += transformedReference;
```

However, since the transformedReference variable appears to be normalized, it may not move the avatar the distance you'd hoped. In that case simply multiply it by some constant MOVEMENT_SPEED for something like such:

```
if (IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    avatarPosition += transformedReference * MOVEMENT_SPEED;
```

Comment: Thanks! Doing what you said I am able to move the camera backward and forward the way it is facing, but how would I go about moving it left and right from the direction it is facing? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: I had hoped the left and right would be fairly easy to figure out. I'm sorry they weren't. To find a perpendicular vector of (x, y), simply swap the terms and negate one: (y, -x) or (-y, x) In your case, since you are dealing with 3d vectors, pretend the y value isn't there and operate solely on the x and z terms. I recommend you brush up on some vector math http://programmedlessons.org/VectorLessons/index.html it will make your life much easier if you're going to be programming 3d games.